# Praw bot works well on local host but not on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, bots, hosting, praw

I have a simple praw bot that goes through unread mentions from reddit and replies to them everything works well on local server but when pushed to heroku the bot does comment but immediately afterwards is removed (probably by reddit spam filters) i am suspecting that heroku's ips are blacklisted as spam by reddit. Is there any way to get around with it, maybe a heroku add on that acts like a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using proxy in your praw source code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).